# How can I resize a image to shape=(None, 321, 321, 3) with name name=None and dtype=tf.float32

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

**Problem**: I am trying to reshape a image to size (None,321,321,3) and also set the name of image to None. I want to match the image dimension requirements to train a machine learning model of specs,

```
TensorSpec(shape=(None, 321, 321, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)
```

**What I have done:** I am using `PIL` to reshape the image. I can convert the image to the required size and RGB band, but have no idea how to make the first argument in the size as `None` and also how to set the name of image to `None`. Please help me find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the batch dimension to your `PIL` image and it should work:

```
image = np.asarray(image)[None, ...]
```